# The Defining Moment

Tags: word, wordplay, knowledge, crossword-clues

> I'm not sure what to put here... but I'll do it regardless!

[image: defining_moment]

```
Popular tourist destination, with “the”
Throwing a Native American weapon
Fruit with a fantastic nickname?
President or patriarch  
Like Nigeria and Chad
“Gold” Egyptian boat
Seattle player
Uproar
```

The answer will be **a thematic title**.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The trick to this is that

> each of the clues has an answer containing AHA, which goes into the central box. (This is hinted by that box and the black square below it forming an exclamation point.)

The answers are:

> BAHAMAS / TOMAHAWKING / PITAHAYA (a.k.a. "dragon fruit") / ABRAHAM (Lincoln or the Biblical patriarch) / SUB-SAHARAN / DAHABEAH / SEAHAWK / BROUHAHA

The grid is filled like this:

> [image]

And the shaded cells

> spell **TAKE ON ME**, a song by the Norwegian band "A-ha".

Comment: Remind me to link [Are math-textbook-style problems on topic?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784) to this post.

Comment: @Rubio Huh? Did you accidentally comment on the wrong post here?

Comment: Nope. There’s a particular phrase of that post...